# javascript: how to keep a transaction (WebSql) alive

Tags: javascript, transactions, web-worker

I have a Worker in which I want to execute my sql queries. But, and that is my problem, I want all these queries to be executed within the same transaction. This is how I have my (not working) Worker right now:

```
db = openDatabase("WorkerFoo", "", "", 1);

if (db) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        self.onmessage = function(e) {
            tx.executeSql(e.data, [],  function(tx, rs){
                    self.postMessage(rs.rows.item(0)) ;
            }) ;
        };
    }) ;
}
else {
    self.postMessage('No WebSql support in Worker') ;
}
```

However, doing it this way, nothing happens (no errors). Any suggestions how to fix this ?

An other (related) question I have is, if a query is blocking the UI thread, because the query is heavy and takes a couple of seconds, will the execution of the query within a Worker fix this problem ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

- The query should not block the UI thread, even if not executed in the web-worker, because it is async (assuming that the target computer has enough multi-threading power that is). JavaScript thrives on non-blocking asynchronous IO.
- You can, for example, pass the SQL code itself to the worker, and have `transactionStart` and `transactionEnd` messages, and only execute the code after receiving a `transactionEnd`.

Note,  the WebSQL specification is [**no longer under work**](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/).

You might want to consider [**IndexedDB**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB), its methods also return without blocking the calling thread. (Again, no web workers are needed, it does however has a synchronous version if you'd like which you can use with WebWorkers (but I think noone implementes yet)).

Good luck!

Comment: I'm building a PhoneGap application for the iPad. And what I'm trying to do is, for a search field, is to fill a list of results during typing. Because the query is heavy, it takes 1 or 2 seconds to complete, the keyboard freezes during this period, and makes smooth typing impossible!

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri Oh, I see what you're trying to do, IIRC indexeddb is not supported in iOS yet, you might want to try this polyfill: http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/ Other than that, what I said should work

Comment: ok, I think I found the problem. I'm using [this](https://github.com/brodyspark/PhoneGap-sqlitePlugin-iOS) SQLite plugin, which states (see 'Known Limitations') that the API will block app execution. How nice :(

Comment: For what its worth, your logic using WebWorkers _should_ work. Good luck :) I'm glad I could help.